# read print out nothing after using fscanf

Tags: c

I'm writing a simple text-based protocol interpreter for server. The server will receive a response in the format of `METHOD [filename]\n[file_size][data]` from socket, where the string length of `METHOD`, `filename`, and `data` vary. `file_size` is the number of bytes of `data`. Since the length of `METHOD` and `filename` vary, I try to use `fscanf()` to capture them. After that, I use `read()` to get `file_size` and `data`. However, the problem is `read()` never prints. I wrote a small case to illustrate my problem:

```
#define MSGSIZE 16 
char* msg1 = "hello world\n#1"; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    char inbuf[MSGSIZE], *buf_1, *buf_2; 
    int p[2], i; 
  
    if (pipe(p) < 0) 
        exit(1); 
  
    write(p[1], msg1, MSGSIZE); 
  
    FILE *fd = fdopen(p[0], "r");
    fscanf(fd, "%ms %ms\n", &buf_1, &buf_2);
    printf("buf_1: %s, buf_2: %s\n", buf_1, buf_2);

    // read never prints
    read(fileno(fd), inbuf, 3);
    printf("buf: %s\n", inbuf); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I would expect `fscanf()` to move the character pointer to '#' in "hello world\n#1", then read should be able to print out following characters, which didn't happen. I'm a bit confused because if I call `fscanf()` instead of read, it would print. Is this because `fscanf()` manipulates file indicator differently from `read()`?

Comment: As an educated guess, `FILE*`s might have an internal buffer, which could have depleted the underlying fd by the time you're attempting to `read` from the it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix operations on the FILE * with operations on the underlying file descriptor.  If you just replace `read` with an `fread`, it should behave as you expect.  The `fscanf` (probably, almost certainly) reads everything from the pipe and stores it in an internal buffer, so your `read` has no data left to consume.  To access the internal buffer, use `fread` or `fgetc` or `fgets`, but don't try to work on the underlying file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing FILE* stream I/O with system calls on the underlying file descriptor is the problem.  Here is a change I made that shows one way to avoid it in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MSGSIZE 16 
char* msg1 = "hello world\n#1\n"; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    char inbuf[MSGSIZE], *buf_1, *buf_2; 
    int p[2], i;

    if (pipe(p) < 0) 
        exit(1); 
  
    write(p[1], msg1, MSGSIZE); 
  
    FILE *fd = fdopen(p[0], "r");
    fscanf(fd, "%ms %ms\n", &buf_1, &buf_2);
    printf("buf_1: %s, buf_2: %s\n", buf_1, buf_2);

    // read never prints
    //retVal = read(fileno(fd), inbuf, 3);
    // replace read() with fgets()
    if(fgets(inbuf, sizeof(inbuf), fd) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error with fgets()\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("buf: %s\n", inbuf); 
    }
    
    return 0; 
}
```